# How can I integrate a CES function?

Tags: functions

I want to know how can I integrate this or if I can do it:

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{C^{\sigma}_{t}}{1-\sigma} e^{-\rho t}dt$

(sigma and rho are parameters)

This problem is part of the common economic problem where I have to do this:

max  $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{C^{\sigma}_{t}}{1-\sigma} e^{-\rho t}dt$

subject to

$C_{t}=Y_{t}-I_{t}$

$Y_{t}=K^{\beta}_{t}L^{1-\beta}_{t}$, beta are parameters not variable

$\dot{K}=I_{t}-\delta K_{t}$, delta is a parameter as well

I know how to solve the maximisation problem using the Hamiltonian, but I am wondering if I can solve the integral or what I need to do it.

Comment: What do all these letters mean?

Comment: C stands for consumption (in economics), sigma and rho are parameters and e is the number e

Comment: Which letters stand for constants and which for variables?  If there are variables involved you have to gives us the formulas.

Comment: Ok, Thanks C_{t}=Y_{t}, and Y_{t}=AK^{\beta}_{t} L^{1-\beta}.Is it enough?

Comment: No, this is not enough.  You are just giving definitions in terms of other undefined symbols.  You should 1) make a complete statement of your problem 2) Write it in the body of the question, not the comments 3) Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format the question so we can read it.  You'll find lots of helpful people here, but no one can help you if you don't say what the problem is.

Comment: @CarolinaGómezCuenca So the function you want integrate is $$f(t)=\frac{A\cdot K^{\beta t}\cdot L^{(1-\beta )\cdot t}}{1-\sigma}\cdot e^{\rho \cdot t}$$

Comment: @CarolinaGómezCuenca I´ve made some corrections: $$f(t)=\frac{\left(A\cdot K^{\beta t}\cdot L^{(1-\beta )\cdot t}\right)^{\sigma}}{1-\sigma}\cdot e^{-\rho \cdot t}$$ Give a reply.

Comment: I had forgotten to tell Thank you!  for your help!